# Searching efficient way of calculating permutations of (13,3) np.array

Tags: python, numpy, combinations, permutation

My inputs in this case are a (13,3) numpy array (where every row contains odds for a soccer game) and an integer working as a limit, for example 2 million.

The numpy array represents a betting system, where outcomes not involved in the system are 0. The other ones are representing odds.

```
system = np.array([[1.14,9.31,17.3],[2.48,3.75,2.67],[2.11,3.64,3.37],
               [3.15,3.83,2.15],[3.95,3.83,1.89],[0,3.54,3.8],
               [0,3.38,3.72],[0,3.74,1.93],[2.53,0,2.8],[0,0,1.38],
               [1.79,4.04,4.24],[4.41,3.33,1.85],[1.64,0,0]]) 
limit = int(2.5*10**6)
```

An "outcome-row" now in this system represents an outcome of the matches (remember, 0:s means not involved in the system). An example of a "outcome-row" for this system is

```
1.14,2.48,2.11,3.14,3.95,3.54,3.38,3.74,2.53,1.38,1.79,4.41,1.64.
```

Now to the question: How many "outcome-rows" in this system contains an odds product (every number/odds in the "outcome row" multiplied with each other, the above "outcome-row" example contain an odds product of 1.4966*10^5) that is GREATER than the given? The problem is for every possible "outcome-row" compare their odds product to the given limit.

I would be extremely thankful for any type of help.

Comment: what is your expected output and what you try so far?

Comment: The functions from the module itertools: 'permutations' and 'combinations' might be useful. A basic tutorial for the same: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/